# Why won't my X session manager start in TightVNC?

Tags: vnc, tightvnc

For testing purposes I'm trying to get a VNC server and client both going on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop, but my X session manager won't start for the VNC server.

Tigervncserver (essentially) doesn't start up. Tightvncserver starts, but the xfce session manager won't start in that session if I did not run `tightvncserver` as root, so when I connect to it with a vnc client I only get the default, barebones X-windows cursor and gray background (i.e. no menus or icons) plus whatever apps I started in ~/.vnc/xstartup, which reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
# these 2 don't work either
#/usr/bin/mate-session &
#/usr/bin/gnome-session &
/usr/bin/startxfce4 &
```

The error messages in ~/.vnc/XPS15:2.log after I run `tightvncserver` non-root are:

```
(xfwm4:21623): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:54:14.168: cannot open display: wayland-0
(xfce4-panel:21648): libxfce4ui-WARNING **: 16:54:15.223: ICE I/O Error
xfce4-panel: Failed to connect to session manager: Failed to connect to the session manager: IO error occured opening connection
(xfce4-panel:21648): libxfce4ui-WARNING **: 16:54:15.223: Disconnected from session manager.
```

When I run as root, I don't see any of those messages. This also works non-root on RHEL 8.7. How can I create a non-root VNC server session in Ubuntu that will successfully start a session manager?